# Recursively rename all files whose name starts with a dash

Tags: command-line, bash, find, rename

In terminal I can rename a single file that starts with a dash, i.e.

```
mv ./-file file
```

I can also rename all files in a directory that start with a dash, i.e.

```
for f in ./-*; do rename 's/-//' "$f"; done
```

However, how can I do this recursively. I have tried using the `find` command, the `rename` command, and a recursive `for` loop. By the way, a lot of the file names have more than one dash. I would only want to remove the first dash. Thanks!

Comment: It's a bad idea having file names beginning with `-` (dash) because that is used as a prefix to signify parametesr for many commands. ie `$ mv a -a
mv: invalid option -- 'a'
Try 'mv --help' for more information.
`

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Thanks. I named a bunch of files this way a few years back before I got to enjoy the wonderful world of Linux. This is why I'm renaming any files I had named this way.

Comment: I like your phrase "wonderful world of Linux" :)

Comment: the proper way to loop over files is   `for f in ./-* ; do ....` (this has many advantages, such as giving you possibility to give "$f" to any program without fearing it takes the filename as options. but there are other advantages as well, which I won't go into details here (look for stephaneChazelas answers, one has a lot of relevant details))

Comment: @OlivierDulac Using `for f in ./-*; do` did not work. It needed to be `for f in -*; do`.

Comment: @jbrock: no, it should work (and avoid many other unpleasant side effects) but then the first argument to rename should be  `s/-//` instead of `s/^-//`

Comment: @OlivierDulac  I made a careless error with including the `^`. We are only looping through files that start with a dash. So, given the `rename` command does not follow with a `g` then it only removes the first instance anyways. Good point, your suggestion works after removing the `^`. Thanks

Comment: [How to remove a file with name starting with “-r” using cli](https://superuser.com/q/689825/241386), [Unix: Files starting with a dash, -](https://superuser.com/q/120078/241386), [How to open files with forward dash in linux](https://superuser.com/q/603792/241386), [Can't rename a file the name of which starts with a hyphen](https://superuser.com/q/510337/241386), [How do I delete a file whose name begins with “-” (hyphen a.k.a. dash or minus)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1519/44425)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using `find` and `rename`:

```
find . -iname '-*' -execdir rename -n 's:./-:./:' {} +
```

`find . -iname '-*'` matches all filenames beginning with a `-`, and then `-execdir ... {} +` runs the command with those filenames as arguments, *after* `cd`ing to the directory containing the files. This means that the command arguments always has filenames of the form `./-foo`. Then it's easy to just match the `-` after the `./` in a regex.

Comment: Very nice. That is exactly what it seemed that needed to be done, `cd` to each directory that contains those files. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

I guess this should work as well

```
for i in $(find . -iname '-*') ; do mv $i $(echo $i | sed -e "s/-//"); done
```