# List & rename files that start with dash/hyphen (-)

Tags: command-line, bash, files

I have a 100+ files that start with a dash (`-`).  I need to know how to do two things:

Example:   `-20200622_142237.jpg`  (File extensions vary, but all have the dash at the beginning.)

1. How do I list (`ls`) files that start with this dash?  Bash seems to think I'm trying to use another parameter.  I've tried using single quotes, double quotes and - in front.  Nothing seems to work.
2. How do I rename all of these files at the same time?  The intent is to rename them without the dash at the beginning.

**NOTE:**  I don't want to change the underscore (`_`).  I just want to remove the dash (`-`) at the beginning of the file.

Lastly, I've already tried this [possible solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882773/recursively-rename-all-files-whose-name-starts-with-a-dash) posted previously, but it does not work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can usually use `--` to indicate the end of command options. So:

1. `ls -- -*`
2. (with the perl-based `rename` command) `rename -n 's/^-//' -- -*`

Remove the `-n` once you are happy that it is doing the right thing.

See also:

- [How do I use filenames that start with a dash “-” as command arguments?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/278000/how-do-i-use-filenames-that-start-with-a-dash-as-command-arguments?noredirect=1&lq=1)